# Using parenthesis in Regular Expressions pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I've a string "This text has some (text inside parenthesis)". So i want to retrieve the text inside the parenthesis using Regular Expressions in C#. But parenthesis is already a reserved character in regular expressions. So how to get it?

**Update 1**

so for the text **"afasdfas (2009)"**

I tried `(.)/s((/d+))` and `(.) (\d+)` and `(.*)/s((/d/d/d/d))`. None of them is working. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, all those forward slashes in your regexes are supposed to be backslashes, i.e., `/s` should be `\s`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either use backslash or [Regex.Escape()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx).

Answer (score 19):

Like this:

```
// For "This text has some (text inside parenthesis)"
Regex RegexObj = new Regex(@"\(([^\)]*)\)");

// For "afasdfas (2009)"
Regex RegexObj = new Regex(@"\((\d+)\)");
```

Edit:

*@SealedSun, CannibalSmith : Changed. I also use @"" but this was c/p from RegexBuddy :P*

*@Gregg : Yes, it is indeed faster, but I prefer to keep it simpler for answering such questions.*

Comment: Took me while to figure out that the second `\ ` is necessary to escape the regex escape character `\ `. I always write my regular expression in verbatim strings: `@"\((.*?)\"` I find it easier to read.

Comment: Or `Regex RegexObj = new Regex(@"\((.*?)\)");`.

Answer (score 4):

For any characters that are "special" for a regular expression, you can just escape them with a backslash "\". So for example:

```
\([^\)]*\)
```

Would capture "(text inside parenthesis)" in your example string.

```
[^\)]*
```

Should  be slightly safer than just "." within the parenthesis, and should also be faster.

Comment: No need to escape the `)` inside a character class.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the parenthesis using the backslash. [C# Reg Expression Cheet Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `\(` , `\)` around your Parenthesis. 
for example:

> (PatternInsideParenthesis)

will be like this:

> `\(`(PatternInsideParenthesis)`\)`