# How to get a string from an input string defined within a frame with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to get the substring in a certain "frame" from an input string. Let's see an example.

I have the following input file:

```
Method(M123426)(123)
Method(M123427)(Zeno)
Method(M123428)(true)
Method(M123429)(444)
```

I would like to get the values from the first occurrence: M123426, 123.
So the frame would be this: "METHOD()()" and I need the values in the brackets.

I created a regex for this:

```
Match method = Regex.Match(inputString, @"METHOD(.+\)\(.+\)");
```

but that would result in the Matches the frame itself as well while I only need the values. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If your example represents all possibilities you should be able to do this by using `string.Split` instead of a regular expression.

Comment: That's just an example. The strings I substituted here with "M123426" and "123" can be very complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^Method\((.*?)\)\((.*?)\)
```

Regexr: http://regexr.com/39ot8

Be sure to enable [`Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) mode.

You'll need to pull the first and second capture groups to get the information you need.

Comment: This seems ok, but why do I need question marks there?

Comment: `*?` means "Match the previous character zero or more times, but match as few characters as possible." [Reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#quantifiers) Example: In `hello world`, the expression `he.*o` matches `hello wo`, but `he.*?o` matches `hello`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@"Method\((\w+)\)\((\w+)\)"
```

Comment: i think this matches all.

Answer (score 1):

You should [escape the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066428/using-parenthesis-in-regular-expressions-pattern) to get appropriate matches and to get the match only from the **first** occurence you should use the `^` line start [anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#Start):

```
string pattern = @"^Method\((.+)\)\((.+)\)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex and get the values from group index 1 and 2. And also  turn on the case insensitive mode to do a case insensitive match.

```
@"(?is)^METHOD\(([^()]*)\)\(([^()]*)\)"
```

It should pick up the first method because `^` in DOTALL mode `(?s)` matches the start of first line only.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qI1qB1/1)

Comment: Thank you Raj. That also works. Unfortunately I couldn't accept this as an answer because there was already another answer before yours.

Comment: That's your wish.. I posted a regex only solution. You don't need to add additional parameters. All within a single regex.